# What is wrong with my solution for this recurrence relation with non-constant coefficients: $a_n = \frac{x}{n} \left( a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} \right)$?

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, recursion

Let the following recurrence relation with non-constant coefficients be defined:

$a_0 = 1$

$a_1 = x$

$a_n = \frac{x}{n} \left( a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} \right)$

**My attempt:**

Let's define our target function as: $y = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$

$n a_n = x a_{n-1} + x a_{n-2}$

$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} n a_n x^{n-1} = x \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + x^2 \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} a_{n-2} x^{n-2}$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( n a_n x^{n-1} \right) - x = x \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( a_{n-1} x^{n-1} \right) - x + x^2 \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} a_{n-2} x^{n-2}$

$y' - x = xy - x + x^2y$

$y' = y \left( x^2 + x \right)$

$\int y^{-1} dy = \int \left( x^2 + x \right) dx$

$\ln{|y|} = \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^2}{2} + C$

With $y(0) = 0$:

$y = e^{\frac{2x+3}{6}x^2}$

But, if I am comparing manually the plots, which I get for the recurrence $a_n(x)$ and the solved function $y(x)$, they become not the same for raising $n$. Even at $|x| < 1$.

**Question a) What is wrong with my solution for $|x| < 1$ ?**

**Question b) Is there an other way to solve it? Especially for for $|x| \geq 1$ ?**

Comment: Where did the $x^2$ come from in $x^2 \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} a_{n-2} x^{n-2}$? It should just be $x$.

Comment: I multiplied on both sides by $x^{n-1}$. I took out of the summation one $x$.

Comment: You need to use $ y = \sum a_n t^n $ for example because $a_n$ depends on $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up $x$ (the parameter in your recurrence) with the formal variable used to write a generating function. That does work here, but not as you attempt to do it.

Define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 1} a_n z^n$, 
Write the recurrence as $(n +2) a_{n + 2} = x a_{n + 1} + x a_n$. Multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$ and decipher the resulting sums:

$\begin{align*}
   \sum_{n \ge 0} (n + 2) a_{n + 2} z^n
       &= x \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n
               + x \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n \\
       &= x \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} + x A(z) \\
\end{align*}$

For the left hand side, it looks similar to:

$\begin{align*}
    z A'(z)
        &= \sum_{n \ge 0} n a_n z^n \\
    \frac{z A'(z) - 0 \cdot a_0 - 1 \cdot a_1 z}
             {z^2}
        &= \sum_{n \ge 0} (n + 2) a_{n + 2} z^n 
\end{align*}$

Putting everything together you have a differential equation for $A(z)$ (linear, first order; thus solvable). For initial value you have $A(0) = a_0$. Having $A(z)$, extracting coefficients gives the $a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

According to your given recurrence, the $a_n$'s (except for $a_0$) will involve $x$, so the derivative $y'$ of $y=\sum_na_nx^n$ will not be simply $\sum_nna_nx^n$ but will also involve the derivatives of $a_n$ with respect to $x$.